# Navigation drawer icon position change

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to change the navigation drawer position to a bit padded from the left like the new playstore icon . I have tried adding padding . But it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a hint of how it should be achieved.
[image: Playstore icon]

Have tried this but doesn't work

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    view.setPadding(50, 0,0,0);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                // accessibility
    )
```

Comment: you dont add any padding you use the v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Comment: can you please provide the solution?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Posted the soln below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the v7-support library to solve the issue . Thanks to @tyczj .

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
            // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
            // accessibility
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            toolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            toolbar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```